# Python int too large to convert to C long(TensorFlow importing)

Tags: python, tensorflow

My Code:

```
import numpy as np    
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds ##The line gives error.
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tfds.disable_progress_bar()
```

**Output**

```
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Already uninstalled and re-installed.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Did you even check the list of issues for `tensorflow_datasets`?  This is a known problem, which they are working on.  https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/issues/3709

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you, I searched a lot but couldn't find it. Of course, I checked the articles. But as the link that you sent, there is no solution for 4.5.0 until the bug is fixed. Except to be downgraded TensorFlow datasets to 4.4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed in `tensorflow-datasets 4.5.2`.

> import tensorflow_datasets as tfds